# Pyparsing: ParseAction not called

Tags: pyparsing

On a simple grammar I am in the bad situation that one of my ParseActions is not called.

For me this is strange as parseActions of a base symbol ("logic_oper") and a derived symbol ("cmd_line") are called correctly. Just "pa_logic_cmd" is not called. You can see this on the output which is included at the end of the code.

As there is no exception on parsing the input string, I am assuming that the grammar is (basically) correct.

```
import io, sys
import pyparsing as pp

def diag(msg, t):
    print("%s: %s" % (msg , str(t)) )


def pa_logic_oper(t):   diag('logic_oper', t)
def pa_operand(t):      diag('operand', t)
def pa_ident(t):        diag('ident', t)
def pa_logic_cmd(t):    diag('>>>>>> logic_cmd', t)
def pa_cmd_line(t):     diag('cmd_line', t)

def make_grammar():

    semi = pp.Literal(';')
    ident = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums).setParseAction(pa_ident)
    operand = (ident).setParseAction(pa_operand)

    op_and     = pp.Keyword('A')
    op_or      = pp.Keyword('O')

    logic_oper = (( op_and | op_or) + pp.Optional(operand))
    logic_oper.setParseAction(pa_logic_oper)

    logic_cmd = logic_oper + pp.Suppress(semi)
    logic_cmd.setParseAction(pa_logic_cmd)

    cmd_line = (logic_cmd)
    cmd_line.setParseAction(pa_cmd_line)

    grammar = pp.OneOrMore(cmd_line) + pp.StringEnd()

    return grammar

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp_str = '''
      A param1;
      O param2;
      A ;
      '''
    grammar = make_grammar() 
    print( "pp-version:" + pp.__version__)

    parse_res = grammar.parseString( inp_str )

'''USAGE/Output: python test_4.py
pp-version:2.0.3
operand: ['param1']
logic_oper: ['A', 'param1']
cmd_line: ['A', 'param1']
operand: ['param2']
logic_oper: ['O', 'param2']
cmd_line: ['O', 'param2']
logic_oper: ['A']
cmd_line: ['A']
'''
```

Can anybody give me a hint on this parseAction problem?
Thanks,

Comment: Any thoughts about upgrading to the latest pyparsing? We are now up to 2.1.6, and it should be stable at this version for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
cmd_line = (logic_cmd)
cmd_line.setParseAction(pa_cmd_line)
```

The first line assigns `cmd_line` to be the same expression as `logic_cmd`. You can verify by adding this line:

```
print("???", cmd_line is logic_cmd)
```

Then the second line calls `setParseAction`, which overwrites the parse action of `logic_cmd`, so the `pa_logic_cmd` will never get called.

Remove the second line, since you are already testing the calling of the parse action with `pa_logic_cmd`. You *could* change to using the `addParseAction` method instead, but to my mind that is an invalid test (adding 2 parse actions to the same pyparsing expression object).

*Or*, change the definition of `cmd_line` to:

```
cmd_line = pp.Group(logic_cmd)
```

Now you will have wrapped `logic_cmd` inside another expression, and you can then independently set and test the running of parse actions on the two different expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are fully right. (The original code had multiple items in these parentheses. To keep the code short, I have removed them...)
Yes, and I have upgraded to latest version of pyparsing.